# Update quote_item custom column

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, cart-items

I added column to sales_flat_quote_item. This column is a attribute of product. When I change in admin attribute value, values is sales_flat_quote_item not updated. Do you have any idea?

**Edit** :

This is my config.xml

```
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <size_of_product />
                    <shipping_cost />
                    <shipping_cost_exp />
                    <shipping_cost_with_zip_code />
                    <shipping_cost_with_zip_code_exp />
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_item>
            <size_of_product>
                <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
            </size_of_product>
            <shipping_cost>
                <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
            </shipping_cost>
            <shipping_cost_exp>
                <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
            </shipping_cost_exp>
            <shipping_cost_with_zip_code>
                <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
            </shipping_cost_with_zip_code>
            <shipping_cost_with_zip_code_exp>
                <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
            </shipping_cost_with_zip_code_exp>
        </sales_convert_quote_item>
        <sales_convert_order_item>
            <size_of_product>
                <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            </size_of_product>
            <shipping_cost>
                <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            </shipping_cost>
            <shipping_cost_exp>
                <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            </shipping_cost_exp>
            <shipping_cost_with_zip_code>
                <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            </shipping_cost_with_zip_code>
            <shipping_cost_with_zip_code_exp>
                <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            </shipping_cost_with_zip_code_exp>
        </sales_convert_order_item>
    </fieldsets>
```

and event in config...

```
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <my_module>
                    <class>My_module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setShippingAttribute</method>
                </my_module>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

And this my observer, where I add attributes to item:

```
   public function setShippingAttribute($observer){
       $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
       $product = $observer->getProduct();

       $quoteItem->setSizeOfProduct($product->getData('tt'));
       $quoteItem->setShippingCost($product->getData('pt2'));
       $quoteItem->setShippingCostExp($product->getData('pt1'));
       $quoteItem->setShippingCostWithZipCode($product->getData('kt2'));
       $quoteItem->setShippingCostWithZipCodeExp($product->getData('kt1'));

    }
```

How to update, when I change value in admin? I don't write cron, who update all table, after one little change...

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more, show us some code? How did you add the column?